# Elasticsearch configuration with magento2 in google-cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

Elasticsearch configuration with magento2 in google-cloud. Elasticsearch is not working in google-cloud external IP address showing error with 500.

Can anybody help me to configure it? What sort of changes do I need to make in configuration and elasticsearch?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on [this](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/01/Deploy-Elasticsearch-on-Google-Compute-Engine.html) site?

Comment: Elasticsearch configuration with magento2 in ubuntu16 instance of google-cloud detailed documentation for showing error with 500